# URL is unknown to Google - Will this still be indexed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo, cname

I am cloaking my website over a site I have developed in replit, but found a way to cloak over a pre-existing domain through managing DNS records and choosing a "cloak" method. This is a simple way to benefit easily from the domain without paying any extra cost, other than buying the domain name itself, which is what I have used.

I know a substantial amount of SEO and ranking, but never have used it. I am trying to get my page indexed by google, this displays this page after testing for a URL inspection.

Could this be a potential block due to "cloaking" as it could be used maliciously or is there any other way to do this in a similar way? Or use of CNAME to display over a domain?

[image]

However, on the status page of my website, it includes:
URL is unknown to Google and doesn't provide much else information on about it.
[image]

Does this information seem normal to be "Not Applicable" as it just wasn't indexed? then why would it say "indexing allowed? N/A" when it also displays it can be reached by google and "could" be indexed and selected as canonical.
[image]

I have done research about this issue, but most of them are old and outdated which doesn't help or provide extended detail about the issue.
I just find it gets confusing as it says "URL is available to google" and it could be selected and scanned as canonical, on the other hand, some research shows that it won't be indexed but never provides any other information about the issue.

The page is a portfolio site, which I am first practicing SEO on with all the the knowledge I have read from the guides that google has fully provided. But I need it to be indexed as a goal that I can use for further websites or highly informational websites I use or create in the future. Hope anyone here has knowledge about Search engine optimization, as the google support is always slow and I have tried to search for other communities but none were available.

Hopefully someone can give some reason or a detailed explanation of what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons described in the description of the [tag:seo] tag

Comment: You can ask this on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yep, thanks I have already asked and found helpful information

Comment: What's the helpful information you've found? @Cohen